# SalesForce.com sandbox guest login

Tags: salesforce

I have a SalesForce.com account that I use for demos. In many cases, I need the users (anyone on the web) to be able to browse the tables without making any changes.

Is there a way to make the tables public or create a guest account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new user and create a special permission set to only allow read access.  Dev orgs come with two users, but you can deactivate/re-activate users to get around the limit.  Or ask SFDC support to add a few more users to your dev org.

There are several places User log-in time and date are logged so you can track them.

Comment: Thanks, @John. A follow up. Is there a way to prevent them from changing the email?

Comment: I don't think so.  But you could set a report up to yourself to be emailed each day listing user account emails.